# Export from PostGIS to SpatiaLite?

Tags: postgis, ogr, sqlite

My PostGIS database contains OSM data from my country. For transportation reasons I want to export a spatial view I created from that data to a SpatiaLite database.

Is there any way to directly extract my PostGIS view to a SpatiaLite db without resorting to a man-in-the-middle (shapefile then SQLite) solution?

Im using Ubuntu Linux, with PostGIS 2.1 GDAL 191.

EDIT:

Here's a single cmd to export to shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" <name-of-folder-to-be-created> \
PG:"dbname=dbname user=username password=pass" \
-sql "<sql query eg> select * from database where <whatever>"
```

If you get a **getsrid(geom) error**, load in your database the `"legacy.sql"`

```
psql -f /path/to/legacy.sql
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the DBManager plugin to QGIS can do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to select from a postgis table, you can use this statement:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco SPATIALITE=yes C:/temp/myfile2.sqlite PG:"host=HOSTNAMEORIP port=XXXX dbname=YOURDB user=YOURUSER password=YOURPASSWORD" -sql "select * from mypostgislayer"
```

If you want to export the whole postgis table, you can use this statement:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco SPATIALITE=yes C:/temp/myfile.sqlite PG:"host=HOSTNAMEORIP port=XXXX dbname=YOURDB user=YOURUSER password=YOURPASSWORD" "mypostgislayer"
```

For further information see the following links:
[ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) and
[spatialite](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/SpatiaLite).

Comment: this seems to be relevant. I will give it a try and then update with results

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to export with ogr2ogr?

Comment: yes I did. I had to load legacy.sql, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done a lot of work in postgis, another alternative might be to import it directly from OSM into spatialite.