# Importing OpenStreetMap historical data with ogr2ogr?

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, import, osm-full-history

I am trying to import historical OpenStreetMap data obtained here:
http://osm.personalwerk.de/full-history-extracts/2014-11-24/continents/

I downloaded the Australia-Oceania file, I am trying to create a spatialite database for Papua New Guinea, the same way I normally do with current data:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES -spat 139.73 0.37 157.64 -12.7 png-full-historic.db australia-oceania.osh.pbf
```

Instead of the expected outcome, I get the following error:

> Error: unsupported required feature : HistoricalInformation
>
> ERROR 1: An error occured during the parsing of data around byte 158

The same command works perfectly with current OSM data.

Can anyone help me to identify what I am doing wrong?

What is the mentioned feature "HistoricalInformation"?

Comment: Are you sure that ogr2ogr supports historical OSM data (*.osh.pbf)? I don't thnk so... Instead, you could use OSM-History-Splitter (https://github.com/MaZderMind/osm-history-splitter) to clip the OSM history file to a BBOX and use the OSM-History-Importer (https://github.com/MaZderMind/osm-history-renderer) to import the clipped file into a PostGIS databse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No, I am not sure if it does (looks like it doesn't). Your additional info therefore is really helping me to go into the right direction. However, I do need an imported spatialite database, as its the file I later distribute to final users (which is a reduced subset in terms of features of the whole data, processed in QGIS). Do you know if there is a way to export the result of osm-history-splitter into a spatialite format?

Comment: It's not possible from the osm-history-splitter's results because these are, as before, *.osh-files. You need to import the clipped result into a PostGIS database. Then it should be possible to load all the tables of a schema from Postgres/PostGIS to Spatialite using ogr2ogr (see here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33064/export-from-postgis-to-spatialite). Hope this helps! In addition: a few years ago I wrote a veriy simple tool called iOSMAnalyzer (https://github.com/zehpunktbarron/iOSMAnalyzer) to analyze various quality indicators using only an OSM history file.

Comment: Consider processing OSM data snapshots that do not contain Historical Information. For Planet-scale data this is available at [https://planet.openstreetmap.org/pbf/](https://planet.openstreetmap.org/pbf/)